colimit of a directed system of $\mathscr O_X$-modules $\mathscr F_i$ of finite type defined over compact space to some $\mathscr F_i$ is surjective


I found this proof on math stacks program in chapter 17 lemma 9.7.. This should not be a difficult proof but unfortuantely I basically understood nothing after reading it. I think it might be that I missed some important intermediate result or definition. Here are two or three questions that I do not understand.

After shrinking $U$ to smaller neighbourhood to smaller open neighbourhood of $x$ we may assume that each $s_j$ comes from a section of $\mathscr F_i$ for some $i\in I$.

Why is that? Is that true the induced map on stalk is surjective for some $i$?

Since $X$ is quasi compact we can find open covering $X=\cup_{j=1,...,m}U_j$, and for each $j$ an index $i_j$ and finitely many sections $s_{jl}\in \mathscr F_{ij}(U_j)$ whose images generate the restriction of $\mathscr F$ to $U_j$.

What is $U_j$? Why is the number of elements in the covering precisely $m$?
Why for each $j$ an index $i_j$ and finitely many sections $s_{jl}\in \mathscr F_{ij}(U_j)$ whose images generate the restriction of $\mathscr F$ to $U_j$? But I think this might has similar argument as the first question.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks:)

Let me try to answer this!

After shrinking $U$ to smaller neighbourhood to smaller open neighbourhood of $x$ we may assume that each $s_j$ comes from a section of $\mathscr F_i$ for some $i\in I$.

As you suspected, the induced map on stalks is surjective. Even better: Colimits can actually be computed stalkwise, that is the preferred map $\operatorname{colim}_i (\mathcal{F}_i)_x \to \mathcal{F}_x$ is an isomorphism for all $x \in X$. (Taking stalks is a colimit construction and colimits commute with colimits!)
In that case, it sounds like you know how to finish (pick a generator in the colimit, take small enough neighbourhoods from the definition of stalks).

Since $X$ is quasi compact we can find open covering $X=\cup_{j=1,...,m}U_j$, and for each $j$ an index $i_j$ and finitely many sections $s_{jl}\in \mathscr F_{ij}(U_j)$ whose images generate the restriction of $\mathscr F$ to $U_j$.

To me, it seems like $m$ is a typo; it need not be the same $m$ as before but that's also not important for the argument. Let me rewrite it.
For every $x \in X$ take a neighbourhood $U_x$ such that there exists $i_x \in I$ such that there exist sections $s_1^x, \cdots, s_{n_x}^x \in \mathcal{F}(U_x)$ coming from some $\mathcal{F}_{i_x}(U_x)$ for some $i_x \in \mathbb{N}$ which generate $\mathcal{F}|_{U_x}$ as an $\mathcal{O}_{U_x}$-module. This is possible by the step that we've just discussed. All $U_x$ together cover $X$, so by compactness we may take a finite subcover. Then, we only have finitely many sections, so we stay at some finite step of $(\mathcal{F}_i)_i$.

Thank you for taking your time to answer my question. Your answer is very helpful. I understood your answer to my second question but not sure about the first one. I just noticed that I did not use the assumption that $I$ is directed. Because $I$ is directed, the colimit can be viewed as disjoint union modulo by a equivalence relation and thus we can assume every element in the colimit comes from a section of $\mathscr F_i$. Is it correct? To complete your proof, assuming $(s_j,U)\in \mathscr F_x$ comes from $(s,V)\in \mathscr F_i,x$, then we just take the intersection $U\cap V$, right?

@user11695417 Yes, directedness is used to give this description of the colimit. I'm not sure I understand your other question.
